Neural network works but erratically
I'm coding a neural network to add and subtract numbers. Below is the code:
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

num_train = 1000

X_train = np.random.rand(num_train, 2)
y_train_add = X_train[:, 0] + X_train[:, 1]
y_train_subtract = X_train[:, 0] - X_train[:, 1]

model_add = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(10, activation='relu'),
            Dense(1, activation ='relu')
            ]
        )

model_subtract = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(10, activation='relu'),
            Dense(1, activation ='relu')
            ]
        )

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model_add.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model_add.fit(X_train, y_train_add, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)


model_subtract.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model_subtract.fit(X_train, y_train_subtract, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)

x = "n" 
while True:
    print("enter first num:")
    x = input()
    if x == "end":
        break

    print("Enter operation:")
    op= input()

    print("enter second num:")
    y = input()

    X = int(x)
    Y = int(y)

    if op == "+":
        predicted_sum = model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Y]]))
        print(predicted_sum)
    elif op =="-":
        predicted_sum = model_subtract.predict(np.array([[X, Y]]))
        print(predicted_sum)

There are two problems with it:
1: It works sometimes, but not always. On some occasions, when I run the program, it outputs approximately correct values for every pair of numbers I input. In other trials, every pair of numbers and operations gives [[0.]] as an output. There seems to be no pattern to it; sometimes when I run it, it just decides to output [[0.]], and it works fine at other times. I don't even change the code between trials.
2: Every time I subtract two numbers with the result being negative, it outputs a small positive number.
Can someone help me fix this?

Try to use other activation functions than relu which gives you ONLY values >= 0

@mz2300 I'm an idiot. Thanks, lol. The issue's fixed, but although I get why it fixes the second issue, I don't get why it also fixes the first. Can you also explain how it only worked sometimes before? I tried it a few times now and it works perfectly every time.

Frankly speaking it's difficult to say why. Probably model needs to have some negative weight values to make more precise predictions. You can try to check layer's weights and biases like this to try to figure it out :)
